# Setup Grafana docker behind nginx reverse proxy in an iframe with token Authentication

Tags: grafana, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup Grafana running on docker-compose behind nginx reverse proxy, it works ok, as long as I is set [auth.anonymous] to enabled=true.

But When I disable anonymous signin, and Try to signin with "Authorization" token in header, I get the error below when navigation to Grafana sub_path:

> If you're seeing this Grafana has failed to load its application files
>
> 1. This could be caused by your reverse proxy settings.
> 2. If you host grafana under subpath make sure your grafana.ini root_path setting includes subpath
> 3. If you have a local dev build make sure you build frontend using: npm run dev, npm run watch, or npm run build
> 4. Sometimes restarting grafana-server can help

my ngnix.conf settings are:

```
server {
  listen 80
  charset utf-8
  location /grafana-dashboard/ {
    proxy_pass http://grafana:3000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  }
}
```

Grafana is running on grafana:3000 from docker-compose.

docker-compose.config.yaml content is:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
    - static-network
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - grafana_stor:/var/lib/grafana
    environment:
    - GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED=true
    - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=10.0.0.3
    - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=http://10.0.0.3/grafana-dashboard/
    user: "472"

volumes:
  grafana_stor: {}

networks:
  static-network:
    ipam:
      config:
    - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

Before accessing 10.0.0.3/grafana-dashboard/ I generate API_KEY using Grafana HTTP_API /api/auth/keys and then pass the returned token on "Authorization: Bearer [token]" header on the client.

Just to clarify, grafana-dashboard aimed to be displayed on an iframe within my webapp, but since I need to pass Authorization header, I make a request to the /grafana-dashboard/ that is served by nginx and then place the 'blob' response on an iframe.

The whole idea is to have "single sign-in" to grafana and to my webapp.
So users that just signed-in to the webapp won't need to login to grafana as well. But if grafana is used directly (not from an iframe), grafana login screen or nginx simple authentication will be required.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work by attaching the API key from the Grafana HTTP API as a cookie. Then, in my `nginx.conf`, I have:

```
location /grafana-dashboard/ {

    # The important line:
    proxy_set_header Authorization "Bearer $cookie_grafana_key";

    proxy_pass http://grafana:3000/;
}
```

This way, you can use an `iframe` as normal and not have to worry about setting headers.

Also, I'm not sure if it's a nginx configuration issue, but when I added the authorization header and API key in an AJAX request—instead of passing the key as a cookie—I was getting the original error as well. I'm not sure what is up there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems:
 1. API key is for API access, but you are trying to load UI (not API, which is available on the `/api` path) with API key
 2. You have enabled auth proxy, but you are not passing any user identity from the nginx proxy

Solution:

1. Solve user authentication on the proxy (nginx): no auth, basic auth, SSO (OIDC/SAML), LDAP, ...
2. Pass user identity from the proxy in the request header
3. Configure Grafana auth proxy correctly for that request header: http://docs.grafana.org/auth/auth-proxy/

Comment: Well, that's not exactly true, API keys do allow authentication for UI as well.
I've tested it on nginx by adding proxy header with Bearer Authentication:

Comment: Now, I was managed to solve the grafana load in an iframe issue by typing an absolute path of grafana-dashboard: https://localhost/grafana-dashboard/ in the iframe src attribute. But I'm still not able to load grafana programmatically using http get request, and then embedding the blob content in the iframe, it gives me the same grafana error, as mentioned in the original post.

I guess I'll try to find a way to generate the API token and place it in a file where nginx can find it and use it just as it does with X-WEBAUTH-USER authentication.
So the token won't be hardcoded.

Comment: I've disabled authentication meanwhile, using [auth.anonymous] enabled=true
I guess my next step will be to try implement SSO between my django webapi, the UI and grafana using OAuth.

Comment: @yudarik Did you find any working solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

As [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3348604/jan-garaj) mentioned above, you are not passing user identity information from the nginx proxy. I used basic authentication and added below line to the location block

```
proxy_set_header  Authorization "Basic <base64 encoded username:password>";
```

which made it work. Better would be to add a new readonly user in Grafana and expose that instead of admin user. You might also want to update the grafana.ini with below configs for more security.

```
session_life_time = 900
allow_sign_up = false
allow_org_create = false
```